# What does "[[]]" mean in regex?

Tags: regex, grep, pcre

What does `[[]]` mean in regex?

```
$ echo '[][]' | grep -oE '[[]]'
[]
[]
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.10
```

Hmm, it appear that it matches `[]`.
(The character sequences `[]`, not `[` or `]`.)
(I've tested it with python's re module, same result.)
Really?
If so, why?

I knew if I want to match `[` or `]`, I should have written `[][]` or `[[\]]`.
(They work in PCRE, grep supports `[][]` but not `[[\]]` since `\` loses special meaning in grep's bracket expression.)
I'm only feeling curiosity.

Comment: Looks like I misread your question.

Comment: @BoltClock I've edited my question a bit. (point out that `[]` is a sequence) I hope it looks more clear now.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `[[]]` actually consists of two concatenated subexpressions: `[[]` and `]`.

- `[[]` is  character class that matches only `[` characters. Having `[` is only possible at the very beginning of a character class.
- `]` is just a normal character if outside of a character class.

Both are concatenated thus your expression matches any character of `[` followed by `]`, which results in matching `[]`.

Comment: If you want to try out more stuff like that, try expressions like `[[]x` or `][[]` :)

Comment: In JAVA, `"foo [ bar".matches("[[]]");` throws a `PatternSyntaxException`: *Unclosed character class near index 3*, because you need to escape the inner brackets: `"[\\[\\]]"`.

Comment: @sp00m Thanks for pointing out this. In some languages, `[[]` is just illegal.